# How to sample rows of a dataframe uniformly while maintaining the relative position of the rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray, uniform-distribution

I want to use `pandas.DataFrame.sample` to sample a given number of rows from a pandas dataframe *uniformly*. However, I want to make sure that the *order* of the selected rows are not contradicting the order of those same rows in the original dataframe. I am not sure how to do that; there is a physical meaning behind the order of rows and I want to preserve that. Maybe it's better to call it decimating the dataframe along its row axis rather than sampling it. What are your suggestions?

Note:

The original dataframe has 83 rows.
I need to create two samples of 25 and 24 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = original_df.sample(25)
# returns the rest(24)
df2 = original_df[~ original_df.index.isin(df1.index)]
df2 = df2.sample(24)
```

The sampled dataframes(df1 and df2) will have the index values from the original dataframe). To get the order in the original data frame you can sort the values by index

```
df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you WithThee, but I need two separate dataframes: one with 25 rows and the other with 24 rows. In each one, the order should be preserved.

Comment: I think the solution works for the described situation. df1 and df2 are your two dataframes with rows in the same order as the original dataframe.